# How to check NSString first value

Tags: xcode, nsstring

I have a string like this NSString *mobile=@"09894598945".
How do i check above string's first character having zero?

Comment: A 5" search in the docs would have yielded => `[mobile hasPrefix:@"0"];`

Comment: What do you mean by "value"? Do you mean character or converted integer value?

Comment: i changed it.it is character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *mobile=@"09894598945";

    if ([mobile characterAtIndex:0] == '0')
    {
        NSLog(@"Yes it contain 0");
    }
```

**Or**

```
if ([mobile hasPrefix:@"0"])
    {
        NSLog(@"Yes it contain 0");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comment `hasPrefix` is best fit here. But you can also use `substringWithRange` function as well. It is enough flexible to check *nth* character of the string as well:

```
if([[mobile substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] isEqualToString:@"5"])
{
   // started with 5
}
```

*EDIT*

As discussed in comment with [Nikolai Ruhe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104790/nikolai-ruhe), function `substringWithRange` will not work for surrogate pairs as mentioned in comments. This is the limitation of this function.

Use `hasPrefix` instead.

Comment: This does not work when the string is empty or starts with a surrogate pair.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, any example of surrogate pair that doesn't work ?

Comment: Any: @"", @"", @"". The problem is that `[substringWithRange:]` produces a broken string when breaking a pair. Try for example NSLog(@"'%@'", [@"" substringToIndex:1])`.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe, Agreed! but i guess it will not work with `characterAtIndex` also. Only `hasPrefix` seems working for me. Edited my answer.

Comment: `characterAtIndex:` really does not return a unicode character (or, in unicode lingo, code point) but rather a UTF-16 code fragment. In the [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) that is the same thing, though. In this respect `characterAtIndex:` seems to work as expected.